# How to obtain a Fourier series for a custom function that generates the periodic "QRS" segment of an "ecg" wave every 1000 millisecond?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy, fft

**Background**

I have been going through an [article](https://www.intmath.com/blog/mathematics/math-of-ecgs-fourier-series-4281) that explained the mathematical reconstruction of the human "ECG" wave, specifically, the "QRS" wave. The function that was used to reconstruct the "QRS" wave is a quartic polynomial of the form: ***f(t) = a(t - b)**4 + h,*** where "a" is a coefficient, "b" is the half period, "h" is the amplitude.

Now, the function that I would like to obtain the Fourier series for is *f*(*t*) = -0.0000156(*t* − 20)⁴ + 2.5. And the function should repeat every 1000 ms.

the curve should start at (0,0), it will pass through (40,0) since the pulse is 40 ms long, and be centered on *t* = 20.

Now, in order to calculate the Fourier coefficients, and plot the Fourier series, I wrote the following program in Python, after following a detailed [article](https://www.bragitoff.com/2021/05/fourier-series-coefficients-and-visualization-python-program/)

The program runs successfully, but it does not generate the "QRS" blips every 1000 ms. It looks like I have failed to find out where the mistake is. I would request the StackOverflow community to look at this question and help me troubleshoot it.

Here is the code that I have written to generate the Fourier approximation of the function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import matplotlib.animation as animation
 
fig = figure(figsize=(7, 7), dpi=120)

 
# Function that will convert any given function 'f' defined in a given range '[li,lf]' to a periodic function of period 'lf-li' 
def periodicf(li,lf,f,x):
    if x>=li and x<=lf :
        return f(x)
    elif x>lf:
        x_new=x-(lf-li)
        return periodicf(li,lf,f,x_new)
    elif x<(li):
        x_new=x+(lf-li)
        return periodicf(li,lf,f,x_new)
 

def ecgFuncP(li,lf,x):
    return periodicf(li,lf,ecgFunc,x)
 

def ecgFunc(x):
    if x < 40:
        return -0.0000156 * (x - 20) ** 4 + 2.5
    else:
        return 0
 

def fourierCoeffs(li, lf, n, f):
    l = 40#(lf-li)/2
    # Constant term
    a0=1/l*integrate.quad(lambda x: f(x), li, lf)[0]
    # Cosine coefficents
    A = np.zeros((n))
    # Sine coefficents
    B = np.zeros((n))
     
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        A[i-1]=1/l*integrate.quad(lambda x: f(x)*np.cos(i*np.pi*x/l), li, lf)[0]
        B[i-1]=1/l*integrate.quad(lambda x: f(x)*np.sin(i*np.pi*x/l), li, lf)[0]
 
    return [a0/2.0, A, B]
 
# This functions returns the value of the Fourier series for a given value of x given the already calculated Fourier coefficients
def fourierSeries(coeffs,x,l,n):
    
    value = coeffs[0]
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        value = value + coeffs[1][i-1]*np.cos(i*np.pi*x/l) +  coeffs[2][i-1]*np.sin(i*np.pi*x/l)
    return value
      
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    # plt.style.use('dark_background')
    plt.style.use('seaborn')
     
 
    # Limits for the functions
    li = 0
    lf = 1000
    l = 40#(lf-li)/2.0
 
    # Number of harmonic terms
    
    n = 100
 
    plt.title('Fourier Series Approximation\nECG Wave\n n = '+str(n))
        
    # Fourier coeffficients for various functions
    coeffsEcgFunc = fourierCoeffs(li,lf,n,ecgFunc)


    # Step size for plotting
    step_size = 0.5

    # Limits for plotting
    x_l = 0
    x_u = 4000

    # Sample values of x for plotting
    x = np.arange(x_l,x_u,step_size)
    
    y1 = [ecgFuncP(li,lf,xi) for xi in x]
    y1_fourier = [fourierSeries(coeffsEcgFunc,xi,l,n) for xi in x]


    x_plot = []
    # Sawtooth
    y_plot1 = []
    y_plot1_fourier = []
    
    x_l_plot = x_l - 13
    x_u_plot = x_l_plot + 300
    plt.xlim(x_l_plot,x_u_plot)
    plt.ylim(-3,3)
    
    
    
    for i in range(x.size):
            
        x_plot.append(x[i])
        # Actual function values
        y_plot1.append(y1[i])

        # Values from fourier series
        y_plot1_fourier.append(y1_fourier[i])


    #     #ecg wave

        plt.plot(x_plot,y_plot1_fourier,c='forestgreen',label='Fourier Approximation')

        
            
        x_l_plot = x_l_plot + step_size
        x_u_plot = x_u_plot + step_size
        plt.xlim(x_l_plot,x_u_plot)
        plt.pause(0.001)
        if i==0:
            plt.legend()
    print(x_plot)
    print(y_plot1_fourier)
    plt.clf()


plt.show()
```

Comment: a decent bit of code, but then you pollute the name space with all the code after `__name__==__main__` .  Be cleaner to tuck that away into a `main()` function at the top...

Comment: i dont think this question should get a downvote (it looks like a good question), so i have upvoted it, although you should isolate the problem to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: whilst wildcard imports are allowed, for clarity it is best to avoid then:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0)

Comment: also if doing matplotlib animation, then refer to this: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html

Answer (score 0):

Two parts need to be changed in order to generate your desired ecg signal and both center around the fact, that you do not want only the ecgFunc parabola to repeat but that blip on top of a baseline for the rest of the 1000 ms.

Therefore the function needs to be modified:

```
def ecgFunc(x):
    if x < 40:
        return -0.0000156 * (x - 20) ** 4 + 2.5
    else:
        return 0
```

Later you set limits in which that function should be repeated. Of course you want to repeat everything between 0 and 1000:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    (...)
    # Limits for the functions
    li = 0
    lf = 1000 # <-- changed from 40
    l = 500 #(lf-li)/2.0 <-- 500 seemed to be correct in my tests.
```

Some comment on your looping:
Looping over the number of harmonic terms AND looping over the data points will become very lengthy. I would suggest to loop only over one these parameters, and to me looping over n seems to be more interesting as you can quickly see how higher order terms approximate the signal better and better.

About your follow up question in the comments:
If you want to keep the axis fixed you should not continously change its limits with

```
        x_l_plot = x_l_plot + step_size
        x_u_plot = x_u_plot + step_size
```

Also, updating the figure becomes increasingly slow. I guess in each iteration a plot it drawn on top of the existing ones, keeping all in the memory. Therefore I would suggest to bring `plt.clf()` into the loop:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # plt.style.use('dark_background')
    plt.style.use('seaborn')

    # Limits for the functions
    li = 0
    lf = 1000
    l = 40  # (lf-li)/2.0

    # Number of harmonic terms

    n = 100

    plt.title('Fourier Series Approximation\nECG Wave\n n = ' + str(n))

    # Fourier coeffficients for various functions
    coeffsEcgFunc = fourierCoeffs(li, lf, n, ecgFunc)

    # Step size for plotting
    step_size = 0.5

    # Limits for plotting
    x_l = 0
    x_u = 4000

    # Sample values of x for plotting
    x = np.arange(x_l, x_u, step_size)

    y1 = [ecgFuncP(li, lf, xi) for xi in x]
    y1_fourier = [fourierSeries(coeffsEcgFunc, xi, l, n) for xi in x]

    x_plot = []
    # Sawtooth
    y_plot1 = []
    y_plot1_fourier = []

    x_l_plot = x_l - 13
    x_u_plot = x_l_plot + 300

    plt.xlim(x_l_plot, x_u_plot)
    plt.ylim(-3, 3)

    for i in range(x.size):

        x_plot.append(x[i])
        # Actual function values
        y_plot1.append(y1[i])

        # Values from fourier series
        y_plot1_fourier.append(y1_fourier[i])

        #     #ecg wave

        plt.plot(x_plot, y_plot1_fourier, c='forestgreen', label='Fourier Approximation')

        # x_l_plot = x_l_plot + step_size
        # x_u_plot = x_u_plot + step_size
        plt.xlim(x_l_plot, x_u_plot)
        plt.pause(0.001)
        if i == 0:
            plt.legend()
        plt.clf()
```

Alternatively you have a look at the animation api as others suggested.

---

Visualizing different number of n I implemented based on your original code the following way:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # plt.style.use('dark_background')
    plt.style.use('seaborn')

    # Limits for the functions
    li = 0
    lf = 1000
    l = 500  # (lf-li)/2.0

    for n in range(2, 30):

        plt.title('Fourier Series Approximation\nECG Wave\n n = ' + str(n))

        # Fourier coeffficients for various functions
        coeffsEcgFunc = fourierCoeffs(li, lf, n, ecgFunc)

        # Step size for plotting
        step_size = 1

        # Limits for plotting
        x_l = 0
        x_u = 4000

        # Sample values of x for plotting
        x = np.arange(x_l, x_u, step_size)
        y1 = [ecgFuncP(li, lf, xi) for xi in x]
        y1_fourier = [fourierSeries(coeffsEcgFunc, xi, l, n) for xi in x]

        x_plot = []
        y_plot1 = []
        y_plot1_fourier = []

        x_l_plot = x_l - 13
        x_u_plot = x_l_plot + 14
        plt.xlim(x_l_plot, x_u_plot)
        plt.ylim(-1, 3)

        plt.plot(x, y1, c='darkkhaki', label='ecg Wave')
        plt.plot(x, y1_fourier, c='forestgreen', label='Fourier Approximation')
        plt.legend()
        plt.xlim([0, 2000])
        plt.draw()

        plt.pause(0.1)
        plt.clf()
```

Here, as suggested, the length of the ecg signal stays constant while the number of n increases in each iteration.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have edited the code, making the necessary changes you have suggested. In my code, I have omitted the loop over the harmonic terms. I couldn't execute the alternate option (omitting the loop over the data points). I am able to generate the ecg plot, but it looks like the curve isn't moving forward. I mean the window axis is changing, but the curve isn't moving across the window. How did it run in your case.

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how that can be achieved.

Comment: I have provided the answer using matplotlib.animation. Thank you for the suggestion and help with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Flow, for your help, and also @D.L, for the suggestion to use matplotlib.animation, for the Fourier series.

I went through the documentation for matplotlib.animation, and herewith I have provided the working animation of the Fourier series approximation of the ECG.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import matplotlib.animation as animation
 
fig = figure(figsize=(7, 7), dpi=96)

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.set_facecolor((0.945, 0.831, 0.886))


 
 
 
# Function that will convert any given function 'f' defined in a given range '[li,lf]' to a periodic function of period 'lf-li' 
def periodicf(li,lf,f,x):
    if x>=li and x<=lf :
        return f(x)
    elif x>lf:
        x_new=x-(lf-li)
        return periodicf(li,lf,f,x_new)
    elif x<(li):
        x_new=x+(lf-li)
        return periodicf(li,lf,f,x_new)
 

def ecgFuncP(li,lf,x):
    return periodicf(li,lf,ecgFunc,x)
 

def ecgFunc(x):
    if x < 40:
        return -0.0000156 * (x - 20) ** 4 + 2.5
    else:
        return 0
 

def fourierCoeffs(li, lf, n, f):
    l = 500#(lf-li)/2
    # Constant term
    a0=1/l*integrate.quad(lambda x: f(x), li, lf)[0]
    # Cosine coefficents
    A = np.zeros((n))
    # Sine coefficents
    B = np.zeros((n))
     
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        A[i-1]=1/l*integrate.quad(lambda x: f(x)*np.cos(i*np.pi*x/l), li, lf)[0]
        B[i-1]=1/l*integrate.quad(lambda x: f(x)*np.sin(i*np.pi*x/l), li, lf)[0]
 
    return [a0/2.0, A, B]
 
# This functions returns the value of the Fourier series for a given value of x given the already calculated Fourier coefficients
def fourierSeries(coeffs,x,l,n):
    
    value = coeffs[0]
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        value = value + coeffs[1][i-1]*np.cos(i*np.pi*x/l) +  coeffs[2][i-1]*np.sin(i*np.pi*x/l)
    return value
     
 
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    # plt.style.use('dark_background')
    plt.style.use('seaborn')
     
 
    # Limits for the functions
    li = 0
    lf = 1000
    l = 15#(lf-li)/2.0
 
    # Number of harmonic terms
    
    n = 100
 
    plt.title('Fourier Series Approximation\nECG Wave\n n = '+str(n))
        
    # Fourier coeffficients for various functions
    coeffsEcgFunc = fourierCoeffs(li,lf,n,ecgFunc)


    # Step size for plotting
    step_size = 0.5

    # Limits for plotting
    x_l = 0
    x_u = 4000

    # Sample values of x for plotting
    x = np.arange(x_l,x_u,step_size)
    
    y1 = [ecgFuncP(li,lf,xi) for xi in x]
    y1_fourier = [fourierSeries(coeffsEcgFunc,xi,l,n) for xi in x]


    x_plot = []
    
    y_plot1 = []
    y_plot1_fourier = []
    
    x_l_plot = x_l-10
    x_u_plot = x_l_plot + 300
    
    ax.set_xlim([x_l_plot, x_u_plot])
    ax.set_ylim([-3, 3])
    
    #ecg wave
    plt.grid(visible=True, which='major', color='k', linestyle='-', alpha=0.3)
    plt.grid(visible=True, which='minor', color='r', linestyle='-', alpha=0.2)
    plt.minorticks_on()
    
    #plotting the graph
    im, = ax.plot([], [], c="black", linewidth=0.5)
    
    for i in range(x.size):
            
        x_plot.append(x[i])
        # Actual function values
        y_plot1.append(y1[i])

        # Values from fourier series
        y_plot1_fourier.append(y1_fourier[i])
    print(x.size)
    
    x_plot = np.array(x_plot)
    y_plot1_fourier=np.array(y_plot1_fourier)
    

    
    
    def func(n):
        
        im.set_xdata(x[0:n])
        print(x[n])
        
        im.set_ydata(y_plot1_fourier[0:n])
        #print(y_plot1_fourier[n])
        
        if x[n] > x_u_plot:
            
            lim = ax.set_xlim(x[n]-x_u_plot, x[n])
            
        else:
            
            lim = ax.set_xlim(x_l_plot, x_u_plot)
            
        return im
    
    
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func, frames = x.size, interval = 100, blit=False)
    
    plt.show()
    # plt.xlim(x_l_plot,x_u_plot)
    # plt.ylim(-3,3)
    
    
    
    # for i in range(x.size):
            
    #     x_plot.append(x[i])
    #     # Actual function values
    #     y_plot1.append(y1[i])

    #     # Values from fourier series
    #     y_plot1_fourier.append(y1_fourier[i])


    # #     #ecg wave
    #     plt.grid(visible=True, which='major', color='k', linestyle='-', alpha=0.3)
    #     plt.grid(visible=True, which='minor', color='r', linestyle='-', alpha=0.2)
    #     plt.minorticks_on()
    #     plt.plot(x_plot,y_plot1_fourier,c='black',label='Fourier Approximation', linewidth=0.7)

        
            
    #     x_l_plot = x_l_plot + step_size
    #     x_u_plot = x_u_plot + step_size
    #     plt.xlim(x_l_plot,x_u_plot)
    #     plt.pause(0.001)
    #     if i==0:
    #         plt.legend()
    # print(x_plot)
    # print(y_plot1_fourier)
    # plt.clf()
#


    
# plt.show()
```

[image]